# How to use row name to sort when it has () in its body?

Tags: pandas, data-science

I'm not able to sort the values as the row label contains brackets().

I'm not sure if my code is correct. I've tried to rename, maybe my code was not correct.

```
GSDP_plot = GSDP_plot.set_index('Item')
GSDP_plot = GSDP_plot.sort_values(by='Per Capita GSDP (Rs.)', ascending=False)
```

Row's name : Per Capita GDP (Rs.)

Expected result: Per Capita GDP

[image]

Comment: Why Dont you melt the df the sort it by the Column??

Comment: How do to melt the df?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure that the 'by' value is presented in your dataframe in rows or in columns depending on the axis parameter. It must be exact value (with parentheses).

As far as I've understood you need to sort columns by values in them for a row. 
There's a serveral ways by which you can achieve that.

Some of them:

### Sort by columns

You can use axis parameter in [sort_values](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) function

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'A':25,'B':20,'C':30}, index = [1])
```

[image: a dataframe]

```
a.sort_values(by=1, axis=1)
```

[image: sorted values of a's dataframe]

### Transpose and Sort

You can [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) dataframe. It'll interchange indexes and columns.

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'A':25,'B':20,'C':30}, index = [1])
```

[image: a dataframe]

```
a.transpose().sort_values(by=1)
```

[image]